# Enumerate AppMessage constructors

Tags: haskell, internationalization, yesod

Let `message/en.msg` file like:

```
Category1: some text 1
Category2: some text 2
    ...
CategoryN: some text N
```

And let next valid code:

```
getHomeR :: Handler RepHtml
getHomeR = do

    (msg :: AppMessage -> Text) <- getMessageRender

    let list = T.concat $ map msg [MsgCategory1, MsgCategory7]

    defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile "homepage") -- <p>List: #{list}
```

then, `list` contains `MsgCategory1` and `MsgCategory7` translations.

I want to do some like:

```
    let list = T.concat $ map msg [MsgCategory1 .. MsgCategory7]
```

but `AppMessage` is not `Enum` derived.

My another one alternative is not valid too (is not `Read` derived too)

```
    let list = T.concat $ map (\n -> msg $ read "MsgCategory" ++ show n) [1 .. 7]
```

In general, how to cast "in real time" `AppMessage` elements?

Thank you very much!

(I love Yesod! :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I found is [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/deriving.html)

```
deriving instance Enum AppMessage
deriving instance Eq AppMessage
deriving instance Read AppMessage
deriving instance Show AppMessage
...
```

(require -XStandaloneDeriving)

Explained:

Change on `Foundation.hs`:

```
-- Set up i18n messages. See the message folder.
mkMessage "App" "messages" "en"

-- Require extension: StandaloneDeriving
deriving instance Enum AppMessage
```

On `site.cabal`:

```
extensions: TemplateHaskell
            QuasiQuotes
            OverloadedStrings
            NoImplicitPrelude
            CPP
            MultiParamTypeClasses
            TypeFamilies
            GADTs
            GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving
            FlexibleContexts
            EmptyDataDecls
            NoMonomorphismRestriction
            StandaloneDeriving
```